# Why are my pings going to 'customer.algx.net'?

Tags: dns, ping

When I try to ping `google.com`, I get the following output:

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (67.89.227.247) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ip67-89-227-247.z227-89-67.customer.algx.net (67.89.227.247): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=25.8 ms
```

My first guess would be that Google (obviously) splits up the load between several servers, and perhaps rather than keep their own servers everywhere, may rent server space from other companies scattered around the globe. The problem is, I can't find any link between Google and the company that owns `algx.net`.

Comment: This may or may not be related, but my SSL fingerprint for https://www.google.com/ does not match what is returned by this site: https://www.grc.com/fingerprints.htm

Comment: Your hypothesis looks correct: Google is using proxies all over the Internet. But I don't see any relation between Google and XO Communications. Check others @IP with `dig google.com`.

Comment: @danielAzuelos This is the output from `dig google.com`: https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/28d41ec0e1f6510ef7f3

Comment: An update, I tested from home, and the domain it returns is `ord30s21-in-f78.1e100.net` [which is owned by Google](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/174717?hl=en)

Comment: Please improve your OQ with: personal or company network, OS (Ubuntu ?), DNS config…

Comment: `67.89.227.247` does return a certificate for `google.com`. It doesn't look like any MITM attack is being attempted on HTTPS traffic. Whether this IP is a legitimate frontend for Google or not is almost impossible to tell for an outsider. If DNSSEC was enabled, it would be possible to verify the integrity of the A record, but it doesn't look like DNSSEC is being used for `google.com`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the `admin` password of your router wasn't changed from its default. Hence your router was easily *hacked* and configured to point to a wrong DNS server.
This DNS server is feeding your network with the mapping to make you go wherever it wants you to web browse `google.com`.

To check this bad possibility, check your DNS servers (`/etc/resolv.conf` on any Unix like OS?).

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` contains a warning about being auto-generated, and this line: `nameserver 127.0.1.1`

Comment: The router is set up to automatically get the DNS settings from my ISP (and it's unlikely someone installed custom firmware to the router just to hide actual the value of the setting). Could my ISP's DNS server be returning this "wonky" DNS result?

Comment: Setup your router to use other DNS servers, like [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/opendns-ip-addresses/), [google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/?hl=en), [Comodo DNS](https://www.comodo.com/secure-dns/switch/router.html), [Norton DNS](https://dns.norton.com/configureRouter.html), etc. Then try again.

Comment: @IQAndreas: \t1)\tIt is unlikely your router provided through DHCP a config with `nameserver 127.0.1.1`. Could you check that this isn't rather `127.0.0.1`?`\n\t2)\tPlease add this useful information within your OQ.

Comment: on Linux `127.0.1.1` should work just like `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

The output of the ping command says that the packet was sent from algx.net. This algx.net has nothing to do with Google. But it is somehow used by your internet service provider. It is probably just a name of a router.  Try pinging yahoo.com. I bet you will still see that algx.net.